# Swift [String] is not convertible to 'String'

Tags: arrays, string, swift

Trying to get this to work but I get the error

"[String] is not convertible to 'String'"

```
 var city = "Atlanta"
 var issueLocation = ["Atlanta","Montreal","Toronto","XXIIVV"]
 let locationRand = Int(arc4random() % 3)
 var passportIdent = "Issue Location: \(issueLocation[locationRand])"
 if (issueLocation == city){
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var city = "Atlanta"
var issueLocation = ["Atlanta","Montreal","Toronto","XXIIVV"]
let locationRand = Int(arc4random() % 3)
var passportIdent = "Issue Location: \(issueLocation[locationRand])"
if (issueLocation == city){
}
```

should be

```
var city = "Atlanta"
var issueLocation = ["Atlanta","Montreal","Toronto","XXIIVV"]
let locationRand = Int(arc4random() % 3)
var passportIdent = "Issue Location: \(issueLocation[locationRand])"
var randCity = issueLocation[locationRand]
if (randCity== city){
}
```

Notice how the line

```
var randCity = issueLocation[locationRand]
```

actually gets the random element in your issueLocation array. You can then use that value to compare with your `city` variable.

Answer (score 3):

You are comparing an array of strings to a single string. That doesn't make sense so the swift compiler is complaining.

`issueLocation` is an *array* of strings, which swift denotes as `[String]`.
`city`, on the other hand is a single `String`. Note the missing square brackets.

It does not make sense to compare an array of strings to a single string. How can one thing equal many things?

That's the error. It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish (you should tell us) so I can't help much more than that.

Comment: I'm trying to choose a specific city from the array, specifically Atlanta. City is set to Atlanta, so I want it to say if issueLocation is Atlanta do so and so.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your if statement:

```
if (issueLocation == city){
}
```

"city" is a string, whereas "issueLocation" is an array of strings. You're trying to compare a string to an array, which won't work.